# Make the new position-indicator on userLocation

Tags: swift, mapkit, userlocation

In my map (using MapKit & MKMapViewDelegate) i show the user location. By default there are a blue circle around the dot. In the new map from apple, the blue circle are updated so it shows witch way the user are going. How do i make my the same? Or i worst case, how do i remove the blue circle?

Answer (score 0):

Similar things are possible with [MKUserTrackingMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkusertrackingmode).

[image]

> how do i remove the blue circle?

Just this

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = false
```

Comment: Oh, but i mean the pulsing blue circle around the showsUserLocation